# add toolbargroup items dynamically in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

```
config.toolbarGroups = [
        { name: 'basicstyles'},
        { name: 'colors'},
        { name: 'links', items : [ 'Source', 'RemoveFormat' , 'Blockquote','BulletedList'] },
        { name: 'clipboard', items: [ 'Undo','Redo'] }
    ];
```

Now I want to add dynamnically **readmore item** to **clipboard**

Here is my editor initialization,

```
editor = CKEDITOR.replace('descr',{
            toolbar         : 'Full',
            resize_enabled  : false
            );
```

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: So do you want to modify the toolbar turing editor's lifetime? This is what you want to do? If so, no, it's impossible: you got to `destroy()` the instance and re-initialize it with a new config.

Comment: as shown in code, i am initializing with new config